# Undo Database Restore in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I accidentally restored a SQL Server 2008 database with a wrong backup. Is there any way to undo this and restore to previous version?

-Vivek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You've replaced what's there with your restore. You would have to treat this the same as someone dropping your database - go to the most recent full database backup you have and then restore all subsequent log backups.

Sorry... you probably have that sick feeling right now. I feel bad for you.

Comment: it's on a windows 2008 server. any chances of retrieving a lost file?

Comment: Nope, sorry....